# SAP Personal WEB IDE upgrade issue

Tags: sap-web-ide

Created in SAP Web IDE on the cloud an application from worklist template version 1.53. Upgraded my Personal Web IDE to the same version using the steps described in the link below:

[​​http://www.saplearners.com/upgrade-sap-web-ide-personal-edition/](http://%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bhttp://www.saplearners.com/upgrade-sap-web-ide-personal-edition/)

Imported the exported application to ​Personal Web IDE and ran it to find out that it was crashing due to components missing. The missing component was sap/f/semantic/SemanticPage.js, which, as I found, is available since version 1.52. Furthermore, when I try to create an application from template within Personal SAP Web IDE, the latest available version shown is 1.44. Explored the contents of Personal SAP Web IDE, plugins folder looks as follows (picked it only because a folder relative to 1.53 is located in there)

[Plugins folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNFQp.jpg)

What exactly do I miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are mixing things up. The version number of the Web IDE Personal Edition and SAPUI5/OpenUI5 are **not the same**.

The latest version of the Web IDE PE is **1.53.1**. It was released 9 months ago (July '17). The latest UI5 Version at that time was **1.44.11**.

[sap.f.semantic.SemanticPage](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.semantic.SemanticPage) is available since **1.46** (UI5, not Web IDE PE). Since this is newer than the UI5 version shipped with the Web IDE PE, this control is not available.

Quick workaround: Use this CDN link while developing: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.46.10/resources/sap-ui-core.js

It points to release 1.46.10 of SAPUI5.

A list of available versions can be found [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html).

Comment: This seems to explain a lot, new to this stuff, I was under the impression that versioning was common for SAPUI5 and IDE and of course that the version of my Personal Web IDE was inline with the cloud. Now things make sense, thanks for clearing out the situation ;-)

Best regards, 

Greg